# Postgres - go - how to find last updated database in Postgres?

Tags: database, postgresql, go, schema, updates

I am having more than 100 database. Each database contains some tables. After performing some operation tables in database got updated. Currently am running a thread which will connect each database and check whether any updation is done or not. Its working fine now. But my need is if am having approximately 300 database and last update will occur in some database only. In this case i dont want connect all database and check. How can i done this. I want some efficient way to do this???

Comment: I guess you mean update like insert/update rows .... So you can use a trigger and dblink, to connect to a log database, and Insert DatabaseName and Time`. That way you only have to chek log db to see who was the last to update. Now if you mean alter tables that may be different.

Comment: this can be done using golang?

Comment: This can be done in postgresql. Golang shouldnt be relevant

Comment: My entire thing is done in golang only.. So i want to do in golang

Comment: So why you use postgresql in your title and tags?

Comment: You can try `SELECT datlastsysoid FROM pg_database;` to get the last system OID in each database. That would be OK for `INSERT`s but I think not for `UPDATE`s and `DELETE`s.